# How to parse an XML document to create an HTML form in Python?

Tags: python, html, xml

I have an XML document like this:

```
    <section name="Personal_details">
        <parameter name="Name" value="String" limit="50" multiple_values="no">
        <parameter name="Phone_no" value="Long" limit="10" multiple_values="yes">
        <parameter name="Address" value="String" limit="100" multiple="yes">
    </section>
    <section name="Academic_details">
        <parameter name="Graduation_marks" value="Integer" max="100" min="0" multiple_values="no">
        <parameter name="PostGraduation_marks" value="Integer" max="100" min="0" multiple_values="no">
    </section>
```

I want to convert this into an HTML form. Is it possible to do this in Python? If yes then how?

Comment: Of course it's possible, but we don't do the work for you.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the module ElementTree that usually comes with Python:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Look for the method `fromstring`.